# m.data is undefined when using custom highlighter

Tags: javascript, jqplot

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/flashvenom/6x6hw3np/

Basically the above is a dumbed down version of a chart I'm working on. You'll see that points 1-3 have a rollover that triggers a function that displays a data from an array. I need the rightmost dot's rollover to work. But it doesn't. I get a `TypeError: neighbor.data is undefined` in jqplot.highlighter.js.

If I put a 0 instead of a (null) as the first point in the dataset and highlighter array (lines 49 and 67), it works. But then I can't hide the zeros using hideZeros: true. Perhaps that option is only for bar renderer?

```
classHighlighter0 = [0, 'ROLL1', 'ROLL2', 'ROLL3', 'ROLL4'];

var plot1 = $.jqplot('c-11-0', [
    [8, 8, 8, 8, 8],
    [0, 7.76125, 5.42035, 7.78345, 9.0069]
  ], classChangeOptions);
```

Any help would be greeeatly appreciated... I've been trying to figure this out on my own for two weeks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to fix this by setting the first point to `NaN`:

```
classHighlighter0 = ['ROLL1', 'ROLL2', 'ROLL3', 'ROLL4'];

var plot1 = $.jqplot('c-11-0', [
    [8, 8, 8, 8, 8],
    [NaN, 7.76125, 5.42035, 7.78345, 9.0069]
], classChangeOptions);
```

[image: Chart with tooltip]

The solution feels a bit hacky, but seems to work. [This Plunker](http://jsfiddle.net/6x6hw3np/10/) shows it working and you don't get the console error.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks! What actually ended up working was using number pair array instead of the above single number array